# Installing npm packages on VS Code running indefinitely

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I've been trying to create a new Angular project on VS Code, running the command `ng new hello-world`, but once it gets to installing npm packages, it runs indefinitely. I've tried to clear cache, ran as an administrator and tried some solutions provided by some sites which is basically what is above, but that didn't work.